# Initiating a class globally

Tags: php, class, oop

To be specific, i have a two class Request and Utils,

```
class Request
{
public function __construct()
{
//constructor method
}
public function request()
{
  $utils=new Utils;
  $consolidated_errors=$utils->array_remove_empty($all_params_error);
}   
public function process()
{
  $utils=new Utils;
  $consolidated_errors=$utils->another_method($all_params_error);
 }                                                                   
}
```

And class Utils,

```
class Utils
{
public function __construct()
{
 //constructor method
}
public function array_remove_empty()
{
  //returns a variable.
  }        
public function another_method()
{
  //returns a variable.
 }     

}
```

you can see that i am initializing the class two times in request class , and my question is  that any way initializing the class globally and using through out the class?

Comment: The code you have posted is a PHP code, why have you tagged it under java ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Singleton pattern

Following demonstrate very basic Singleton example for your class

```
public class Utils {
  private static Utils uniqInstance;

  private Utils() {
  }

  public static synchronized Utils getInstance() {
    if (uniqInstance == null) {
      uniqInstance = new Utils();
    }
    return uniqInstance;
  }
  // other useful methods here
}
```

get the instance using static-factory pattern

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not look like Java to me, but anyway,

You could create the class at a class level `private Utils myUtuils = new Utils ();`

or
have the class as a static class and then just use it directly in your method

```
public function process()
{
  consolidated_errors= Utils.another_method($all_params_error);
 }                                                                   
}
```